# how to select a div within a list in jquery

Tags: jquery, selector, qtip

I'm following a tutorial for a menu bar and I'm having trouble adapting it to use qTip because I cant seem to be able to find a way to select a particular element.

```
 <div class="leftside">
        <!-- all things in floating left side -->
        <ul id="social">
            <li><a class="rss" href="#"></a>
                <!-- icon -->
                <div id="tiprss" class="tip">
                    <!-- tooltip -->
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="#">580 Readers</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#"><small>[Subscribe]</small></a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </li>
```

I'm trying to fetch the div "tiprss" which I can do by name, but I actually want, for the currently hovered li its child "tip" class... is this doable?

The point is so that I can pass the html in this div tag into qTip as content.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can bind a `mouseover` event to `$('#social li')` like so:

```
$('#social li').bind('mouseover',function(e){
    $('#qTipID').html($(this).find('.tip').html());
});
```

I assume the qTip disappears on `mouseout`, so no need to remove anything since it will be replaced on next `mouseover`.  [Here's a working example.](http://jsfiddle.net/2NMeZ/)

Comment: I tried the others but this one worked straight off which was great. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

jquery has a [hover function](http://api.jquery.com/hover/) that handles this nicely

```
$('.tip').hover(
     function() {
          var tipdiv = $(this);
          // mouse is over!
     },
     function() {
          var tipdiv = $(this);
          // mouse out!
     }
);
```

Comment: +1 as I used a combination of hover and the answer further down.

Answer (score 0):

Try:  `$('li div.tip').text()`